# PostGreSQL: encoding problem when createdb and LC_ALL=C

Tags: linux, fedora, postgresql

I have a script that run the following command to create a database:

```
createdb --template template0 -E SQL_ASCII foobar
```

I get the error:

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding SQL_ASCII does not match locale en_US.UTF-8
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding UTF8.
```

I can understand why the locale can be a problem, so I decided to set `LC_ALL=C` but it doesn't work still:

```
$ LC_ALL=C createdb --template template0 -E SQL_ASCII gnattracker
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding SQL_ASCII does not match locale en_US.UTF-8
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding UTF8.
```

Do you have an idea what the problem could be?

I am using Fedora 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks voretaq7, now I understand the problem.

So, what is it?

The problem is that `createdb` vdoesn't read the environment variable `LC_ALL` when a template database is used. With the flag `-e` we can se it is issuing the following command to the server:

```
CREATE DATABASE gnattracker ENCODING 'SQL_ASCII' TEMPLATE template0;
```

In that particular case, the locale information from the template is used for the new database. And the encoding is incompatible with these locale settings. This was probably because `LC_ALL` was not set to `C` when the databases were initialized with `initdb`.

The simple solution would be to change the locale settings from `template0`. So I tried:

```
ALTER DATABASE template0 SET LC_CTYPE TO 'C';
ALTER DATABASE template0 SET LC_COLLATE TO 'C';
```

The problem is that locale settings can't be changed at all. Bad luck. So, I resolved to clone `template0` with new locale settings and replace the existing `template0` with its clone:

```
CREATE DATABASE template0b TEMPLATE template0 LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C';
DROP   DATABASE template0;
ALTER  DATABASE template0b RENAME TO template0;
```

The newt thing is to tell PostGreSQL that `template0` is a template and that you don't have to be the owner of the database to copy it:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template0';
```

That solved my problem ([see also this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418935/trashed-postgres-template1/3235208)).

Comment: This does not work. "ERROR:  parameter "lc_ctype" cannot be changed"

Answer (score -1):

Check your other locale environment variables, and/or see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/locale.html for how to override the locale setting.